# Getting a TOISolver ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException creating a tile based game

Tags: jbox2d, tiles

I've been making a tile-based game on java using jBox2D.For adding tiles to physical world I use static bodies which are stored in updating ArrayList(i use PhysicBlock class as a wrapper). Whenever I call body.setTransform(...) only half of the blocks is being added(there is always a 1-block-gap between them).When I try to insert a block between or under any of them  I get the following when a dynamic body collides with any of them:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
at org.jbox2d.dynamics.contacts.TOISolver.initialize(TOISolver.java:99)
at org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.solveTOI(World.java:1235)
at org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.solveTOI(World.java:1053)
at org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.step(World.java:565)
at org.projectez.world.World.updateActiveBlocks(World.java:40)
at org.projectez.world.World.update(World.java:94)
at org.projectez.core.UpdateThread.update(Core.java:117)
at org.projectez.core.UpdateThread.run(Core.java:87)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Fragment of the World class(not jbox2d world,this class represents all blocks and GameObjects in game, it has jbox2d world as a field:

```
...
public ArrayList<PhysicBlock> activeBlocks=new ArrayList<PhysicBlock>();
public World(int x,int y)
{
    worldX=x;worldY=y;
}
public void updateActiveBlocks()
{
    physWorld.step(1/100f,2, 2);
    for(PhysicBlock pb : activeBlocks)
    {
        pb.nullify();
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
    {
        activeBlocks.get(counter).redefine(i, 10, BlockRegistry.blockStone);
        counter++;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
    {
        activeBlocks.get(counter).redefine(i, 11, BlockRegistry.blockStone);
        counter++;
    }
    ...
```

PhysicBlock class:`public class PhysicBlock 
{
    public BodyDef boxDef;
    public Body box;
    public FixtureDef boxFixture;
    public int i;
    public int j;
    public PhysicBlock(int i,int j,org.jbox2d.dynamics.World physWorld, Block block)
    {
        boxDef=new BodyDef();
        boxDef.position.set(i/2+0.25f,-j/2-0.25f);
        boxDef.type = BodyType.STATIC;
        PolygonShape boxShape = new PolygonShape();
        boxShape.setAsBox(0.25f, 0.25f);
        box = physWorld.createBody(boxDef);
        boxFixture = new FixtureDef();
        boxFixture.density = 1;
        boxFixture.shape = boxShape;
        boxFixture.restitution = 0f;
        box.createFixture(boxFixture);
        box.setFixedRotation(true);
        if(block==null) box.setActive(false);
    }
    public void redefine(int i,int j,Block block)
    {
        this.i=i;
        this.j=j;
        box.setTransform(new Vec2(i/2+0.25f,-j/2-.25f),0f);
        if(block==null) box.setActive(false);
        else box.setActive(true);
    }
    public void nullify()
    {
        box.setActive(false);
    }
}`

Comment: What' the line highest up on the error's stack trace that is part of your code?

Comment: physWorld.step(1/100f,2, 2);